# Shapes in containers are not shown on the stage

Tags: javascript, html, containers, shapes, easeljs

in this code [JSFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/4AP48/15/) I try to put one big container on the stage. This one big container has other 2 containers that each contain a shape.
I want to see the shapes on the stage but I can not mange to do it.
The compiler throws no errors.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
// CREATE STAGE //
var stage = new createjs.Stage("myCanvas");

// CREATE TIME_CONTAINER //
var time_container = new createjs.Container();
time_container.x = stage.x;
time_container.y = stage.y;
time_container.width =  stage.width;
time_container.height = stage.height;

// CREATE DEV CONTAINER //
var dev_container = new createjs.Container();
dev_container.x = time_container.x;
dev_container.y = time_container.y;
dev_container.width = time_container.width / 2;
dev_container.height = time_container.height;
var dev_shape = new createjs.Shape();
dev_shape.graphics.beginFill("#ff0000").drawRect(dev_container.x,dev_container.y,dev_container.width,dev_container.height);




 // CREATE PLAYER CONTAINER //
 var player_container = new createjs.Container();
 player_container.x = time_container.width / 2;
 player_container.y = time_container.y;
 player_container.width = time_container.width / 2;
 player_container.height = time_container.height;
 var player_shape = new createjs.Shape();
 player_shape.graphics.beginFill("#ff0000").drawRect(player_container.x,player_container.y,player_container.width,player_container.height);



// ADD TIME_CONTAINER TO THE STAGE //
stage.addChild(time_container);
time_container.addChild(dev_container,player_container);
dev_container.addChild(dev_shape);
player_container.addChild(player_shape);
stage.update();
```

Comment: stage.width and height are undefined !

Comment: @ProllyGeek I have my canvas like this  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1600" height="1200"></canvas> 
Do I still have to define the width and hight of the stage if I created it from the canvas that allready has width and height?

Comment: no you have just missed stage.canvas.width; and stage.canvas.height; , thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// CREATE STAGE //
var stage = new createjs.Stage("myCanvas");

// CREATE TIME_CONTAINER //
var time_container = new createjs.Container();
time_container.x = stage.x;
time_container.y = stage.y;

time_container.width =stage.canvas.width;
time_container.height =stage.canvas.width;

// CREATE DEV CONTAINER //
var dev_container = new createjs.Container();
dev_container.x = time_container.x;
dev_container.y = time_container.y;
dev_container.width = time_container.width / 2;
dev_container.height = time_container.height;
var dev_shape = new createjs.Shape();
dev_shape.graphics.beginFill("#ff0000").drawRect(dev_container.x,dev_container.y,dev_container.width,dev_container.height);


// CREATE PLAYER CONTAINER //
var player_container = new createjs.Container();
player_container.x = time_container.width / 2;
player_container.y = time_container.y;
player_container.width = time_container.width / 2;
player_container.height = time_container.height;
var player_shape = new createjs.Shape();
player_shape.graphics.beginFill("#ff0000").drawRect(player_container.x,player_container.y,player_container.width,player_container.height);



// ADD TIME_CONTAINER TO THE STAGE //
stage.addChild(time_container);
time_container.addChild(dev_container,player_container);
dev_container.addChild(dev_shape);
player_container.addChild(player_shape);

stage.update();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/4AP48/17/

Comment: you answer helped me alot but I still can not show the second container on the stage. do you know this is not working?

Comment: it is there just change its color

Comment: I allready did this. the second one is not added to the stage

Comment: the console says that both dev and player containers are not defined ! weird !

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get both shapes on the stage. The shape properties (x,y,width,height) were not right. I took the shape properties from the first shape and now it works fine.
Here is the code:

```
// CREATE STAGE //
var stage = new createjs.Stage("myCanvas");

// CREATE TIME_CONTAINER //
var time_container = new createjs.Container();
time_container.x = stage.x;
time_container.y = stage.y;
time_container.width =stage.canvas.width;
time_container.height =stage.canvas.width;

// CREATE DEV CONTAINER //
var dev_container = new createjs.Container();
dev_container.x = time_container.x;
dev_container.y = time_container.y;
dev_container.width = time_container.width / 2;
dev_container.height = time_container.height;
var dev_shape = new createjs.Shape();
dev_shape.graphics.beginFill("#00b35a").drawRect(dev_container.x,dev_container.y,dev_container.width,dev_container.height);


// CREATE PLAYER CONTAINER //
var player_container = new createjs.Container();
player_container.x = time_container.width / 2;
player_container.y = time_container.y;
player_container.width = time_container.width / 2;
player_container.height = time_container.height;
var player_shape = new createjs.Shape();
player_shape.graphics.beginFill("#ff0000").drawRect(dev_container.x,dev_container.y,dev_container.width,dev_container.height);



// ADD TIME_CONTAINER TO THE STAGE //
dev_container.addChild(dev_shape);
player_container.addChild(player_shape);
time_container.addChild(dev_container);
time_container.addChild(player_container);
stage.addChild(time_container);
stage.update();
```

And here is the link to [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4AP48/22/)